# Best practice of Cache-Control for Bad Request (400)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cache-control

Currently I have the following action which will tell the client to cache the response for 1200 seconds:

```
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 1200)]
[HttpGet("universities")]
public IActionResult GetAllUniversities(string location)
{
    if (/*location not found*/)
      return BadRequest();

    ...
    return Ok(universities);
}
```

In the response header, when it returns Ok (200), I received the following value:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=1200
```

Which is perfect as expected.

When I passed the wrong location to the API and the API returns BadRequest (400), it also returns the same Cache-Control value as above.

My question is, is this the best practice? Or should it return `no-cache, no-store` instead for 400? If it should, how do I return `private, max-age=1200` when it's 200 and return `no-cache, no-store` in .NET Core for this particular action only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I need to satisfy the following conditions:

1. Do not return response cache header value if the response code is not 200.
2. Returns `private, max-age=1200` if the response code is 200.
3. The solution should be applied to certain controller action only.

So I decided to create an attribute class that implements `IResultFilter` instead.

```
public sealed class PrivateCacheControlResultFilterAttribute : Attribute, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.OnStarting(state =>
        {
            var httpContext = ((ResultExecutingContext)state).HttpContext;

            if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                httpContext.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                {
                    Private = true,
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1200)
                };
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }, context);
    }
}
```

Then use this new attribute on the `GetAllUniversities` action.

```
[PrivateCacheControlResultFilter]
[HttpGet("universities")]
public IActionResult GetAllUniversities(string location)
{
    if (/*location not found*/)
      return BadRequest();

    ...
    return Ok(universities);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Response Caching Middleware in ASP.NET Core** which only caches responses for 200 status code responses and ignores other error responses.

For more information how to implement refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x